# Что это за кодировка?

Tags: json

Получаю JSON типа:

```
{
    id: 89734625,
    name: "\08\0f\0d\07"
}
```

Что за данные содержатся в поле `name`? И как их можно раскодировать?

Comment: это последовательность байтов, кодировку придется угадать

Comment: Все из диапазона управляющих символов, ни в одной кодировке читаемые символы так не кодируются. Возможно они шифрованные или представляют отнюдь не имя